# gmap4rails in ActiveAdmin: maps does not appear

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, gmaps4rails

In try to use gmaps4rails in my ActiveAdmin / Rails app. To do so, I have added the following in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'gmaps4rails'
```

and ran a "bundle". I updated the 'show' method in app/admin/device.rb file with:

```
show do 
  attributes_table do
    row :name
  end

  # Get device location
  @markers = Location.all.to_gmaps4rails
  div do
    render "map"
  end
end
```

In the app/views/admin/devices/_map.html.erb I have the following code:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'gmaps4rails' %>
<%= gmaps4rails(@markers) %>
<%= yield :scripts %>
```

In app/assets/javascripts/application.js:

```
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

And in my app/models/location.rb:

```
class Location < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_gmappable

  attr_accessible :latitude, :longitude

  def gmaps4rails_address
    "#{self.latitude}, #{self.longitude}" 
  end

  def location
    [:latitude, :longitude]
  end
end
```

When I go on the show page of a device, the map does not shows up (all blank). Is there any configuration I missed ?

**UPDATE**

I have checked with chrome developer tools and noticed the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ;
```

that make reference to the line:

```
Gmaps.map.markers = ;
```

Comment: Weird error, the to_gmaps4rqils is speced to always return something, at least an empty array. I wonder if your instance variable is really passed to the Gmaps method

Comment: Regarding what I've described, do you thing some files (css, js) are not loaded correctly ?

Comment: i fear `@markers` is `nil` but the gem never spits `nil`

Comment: In the show method, when I display the @markers, it's not nil, but when I display it in the map template, it is.... You'r right, the instance variable is not passed to the template... What can be the cause ?

Comment: I can't tell, I've never used active admin.

Comment: Ok, this is fixed now :) Variable was not passed the same way as regular rails app. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix with the following:

```
div do
  markers = Location.all.to_gmaps4rails
  render "map", { :markers => markers }
end
```

and :

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'gmaps4rails' %>
<%= gmaps({
        "map_options" => { "zoom" => 2, "auto_adjust" => false},
        "markers"     => { "data" => markers }
        })
%>
<%= yield :scripts %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to load the Javascript files in the **/config/initializers/active_admin.rb;** search for the section:

```
# To load a javascript file:
#   config.register_javascript 'my_javascript.js'
```

Also, I think you should add the CSS files (if is not appearing) into the same file.

Remember that ActiveAdmin manages its own Javascript file, named **active_admin.js**; you can try loading the Javascript files in this JS; some time ago I had a similar problem and I only was able to solve it adding the files in the initializer.

Comment: I have added "config.register_javascript 'gmaps4rails.js'" in active_admin initializer, but I get the 'http://localhost:8080/assets/gmaps4rails.js 404 (Not Found) '. I did not think I add to add the js manually in the assets.

Comment: Did you load the files with the full path?

Comment: I have added the following in initializer/active_admin.rb:  "config.register_javascript 'gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js.coffee'" and copied gmaps4rails.googlemaps.js.coffee into public/assets, the file is found but I still have the same error. I though adding the necessary 'require' statement in application.js where enough though.